# Geodesics on the 3-Sphere vs Hopf Circles

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

Regarding $\mathbb S^3$, the $3$-sphere:

I'm trying to reconcile claims that seem contradictory. On page 2 of this article: "[Sculptures in $\mathbb S^3$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4952.pdf)" by Schleimer and Segerman one finds the quote:

"Any plane, meeting the origin in $\mathbb R^4$, cuts $\mathbb S^3$ in a great circle. The great circles are the geodesics, or locally shortest paths, in the geometry on $\mathbb S^3$. Just as for the usual sphere, $\mathbb S^2$, two distinct great circles meet at two points, [$x$ and the antipode of $x$]"

That makes sense to me.

However on page 103 of "Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology" by William Thurston, I find the quote: "Each complex line (one-dimensional subspace) in $\mathbb C^2$ intersects $\mathbb S^3$ in a great circle, called a Hopf Circle. Since **exactly one Hopf circle passes through each point of $\mathbb S^3$**,..."

A one-dimensional line in $\mathbb C^2$ is analagous to a  plane in $\mathbb R^4$.

The first quote says more than one great circle can pass through a single point of $\mathbb S^3$, while the second quote says the opposite.

What am I confusing here?

Secondly, it sounds like Thurston is saying that the plane does not need to intersect the origin for its intersection with $\mathbb S^3$ to form a geodesic. Is that correct? If so, how does on make a small circle on $\mathbb S^3$?

Comment: With a given complex structure, not every great circle is a Hopf circle. So it's logically consistent that only one Hopf circle intersect any given point and every point intersects many great circles. Also, your first quote is incorrect, it's definitely possible for distinct great circles to never intersect in $S^3$. In fact, $S^3$ contains flat tori which are "ruled" by two families of disjoint great circles!

Comment: Maybe you like to put it up as an answer.. as it negates both the premises.

Comment: can you give me an example of a great circle on S3 that is not a hopf circle?  Hopf Circles are all circles formed by the intersection of S3 with lines through the origin, e.g. lines of the form z2=a.z1 where a is a complex number which can be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"Complex"**

In the second quote, they are referring to complex line. So if $v\in \mathbb S^3$ the plane spanned by $\{v, \sqrt{-1} v\}$ is the unique complex line passing through $v$. Thus there is a unique Hopf circle passing through $v$.

However there are lots of real two dimensional planes (which are not complex) passing through $v$, and thus lots of great circles passing through $v$.

Also, let me point out (as anon [did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484694/geodesics-on-the-3-sphere-vs-hopf-circles#comment5134669_2484694)) that two great circles in $\mathbb S^3$ might not intersect: just take two 2-dimensional plane $L_1$, $L_2$ in $\mathbb R^4$ which interesct only at the origin. Then the great circles cut out by $L_1, L_2$ will not intersect in $\mathbb S^3$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a real two dimensional plane in R4 that goes thru the origin that cannot be identified with a line in C2 that goes thru the origin?

Comment: The line spanned by (1,0) and (0,1) in $\mathbb C^2$ is such an example. @BobWoodley